# Capture optional capture group next to first group

Tags: regex, capture-group

Given the two strings

```
hello/world/thomas
```

And:

```
hello/world
```

I have the following regex

```
hello/(.+)(/(.+))?
```

The second group is optional.

I'd expect the following group matches:

```
['world', 'thomas']
```

But I am getting:

```
['world/thomas']
```

And the second string works as expected:

```
['world']
```

How can I produce the expected results.

https://regexr.com/3kh06

Comment: Use negated character classes: [`hello/([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/n07ieq/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just out of curiosity (and for my own knowledge) is `[]` considered to be a class, a set, or both? The terms seem to be used interchangeably.

Comment: @ctwheels In POSIX context, it is called a *bracket expression* (so as not to confuse with POSIX character classes like `[:digit:]`). In NFA world, it is usually called a character class, and sometimes a character set (used interchangeably).

Comment: Just use a lazy quantifier in the first group

Comment: What would you want to match if it were `hello/world/today/is/thomas/tommorrow/is/james` ? Anyway, if positional, you can't use something like the `.+?` without anchoring it with a character after it. If all is optional after it, it chooses to match nothing. Best to stick with a negated class `[^/]*` with optional quantifier if positional.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern - `hello/(.+)(/(.+))?` - matches `hello/`, then `(.+)` grabs all the rest of the line placing it into Group 1 and then checks if it can match the rest of the text (at this point, empty text at the end of the string) with the `(/(.+))?` pattern - and it can since it can match an empty string due to the `?` quantifier (= *zero or more repetitions*).

You may replace `.` with `[^/]` [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) to avoid matching over all chars other than line break chars:

```
var rx = new RegExp("hello/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?", "g")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n07ieq/2)

**Description**:

- `hello/` - a literal substring
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: any one or more chars other than `/`
- `(?:/([^/]+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `/` - a `/` char
  - `([^/]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `/`.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['hello/world/thomas', 'hello/world'];      // Demo strings
var rx = new RegExp("hello/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?", "g") // Regex (constructor used due to many / inside
for (var s of strs) {                                  // Demo loop
  var res = [], m;
  while(m = rx.exec(s)) {                              // Check for multiple matches
    res.push(m[1]);                                    // Adding Group 1 to results
    if (m[2]) res.push(m[2]);                         // Adding Group 2 to results if exists
  }
  console.log(s, res);                                // Demo result display
  
}
```